# Where are stored layout tabs for the workspace in VS Code?

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code, project

I want to know where the stored layout tabs of the workspace are.

Because when I open .code-workspace file on different PC, the layout is not saved in the file.

The layout still remain sames if I open the workspace in the main PC.

[Layout tabs in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvcel.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting Sync Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) might be helpful:

> It Syncs
>   All extensions and complete User Folder that Contains
>
> 1. Settings File
> 2. Keybinding File
> 3. Launch File
> 4. Snippets Folder
> 5. VSCode Extensions & Extensions Configurations
> 6. Workspaces Folder

You should give them a token access from github, And press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. A complete doc is found in the link.

Comment: thanks for your comment, this plugin is very amazing but it seem he don't sync tabs layout, or may be I miss something

Comment: @M.Bourdin I think it should be synced in number 6: Workspaces Folder, Souldn't it? Try one.

Answer (score 0):

Setting facilitate synchronisation of usder preferences
[image]